# MATLAB GUI: How do I turn off a push button when a text box is empty?..... Also, how can I produce error message when wrong file type is opened?

Tags: windows, matlab, wav

I am making a GUI in Matlab (I am a newbie to this) and I am stuck on two things:

1) I would like to prevent the user from selecting a file type other than .wav. I have managed to get the open dialog box to display only .wav files but that doesn't stop them selecting all files and opening another file type. This breaks the rest of my GUI. How can I defend against this?

2) I would like to prevent my 'Compute' push button being selectable when a certain text box is empty. How can I do this? I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
p = get(handles.textbox,'String'); 
    if isempty(p)
         set(handles.compute, 'enable', 'off');
    else
         set(handles.compute, 'enable', 'on');
    end
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you very much

Best regards

Comment: What you need to do is disable the button if the text box is empty. (And if you were hoping for a more useful answer, perhaps you could tag your question with the name of your OS, development environment and programming language.)

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for some reason I thought this was a matlab forum so didn't occur to me to put the program. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

1) you can throw an error and reset the selection if the file type doesn't have the extension '.wav'. Check the file name extension using the `fileparts` command.

2) Ensure that (a) if the textbox starts out empty, the button starts out with 'enable' set to 'off' and (b) your logic of testing the text box is inside the text box's callback. If you're setting the contents of the textbox from some other function, then the textbox's callback is not normally called. In that case, you should manually call the textbox's callback within that other function after setting the textbox's string, like:

```
set(handles.textbox, 'string', 'some_file.wav');
textbox_Callback(handles.textbox, eventdata, handles);
```